# Git hangs on push --set-upstream

Tags: git, push, bare

I just recently reinitialized a bare git repository that we have been using for quite awhile and i of course have forgotten the specific settings I setup on it so i am encountering problems. I am able to init the repo, clone it to my local computer, and create branches. I am also able to set the upstream branch on my local computer. However, i have a colleague who is trying to do the same but when he tries to push the upstream, it will prompt him for his password and then will come back with "Total 0 (delta 0) reused 0 (delta 0) and will hang there until he CTLR+C out of it. We have tried reinitializing multiple times with now luck. is this a repository issue or is something else going on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out that this was a permissions issue. --shared needs to be specified when the creating the repository

`git init --bare --shared`